# Extend Phaser.Text class

Tags: javascript, extends, phaser-framework

I'm using [this Es6 Phaser boilerplate](https://github.com/lean/phaser-es6-webpack) and in there, there's a Phaser.Sprite extension called Mushroom:

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'

export default class extends Phaser.Sprite {

  constructor ({ game, x, y, asset }) {
    super(game, x, y, asset)

    this.game = game
    this.anchor.setTo(0.5)
  }    
  update () {
    this.angle += 1
  }    
}
```

So I tried to replicate this in the Phaser.Text Class like this:

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'    

export default class extends Phaser.Text {
  constructor({game, x, y, text, style}){
    super(game, x, y, text, style)

    this.game = game
    this.anchor.setTo(0.5)

  }    
}
```

and then called it on the Game.js file, just like in the example:

```
this.texto = new Texto({
      game: this,
      x: 0,
      y:0,
      text:"hola mundo"
    })

    this.game.add.existing(this.texto)
```

but this is the result:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolution' of undefined**

How can I properly extend Phaser.Text or create a reusable class?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the error is caused in the Text object? resolution is a property of a Text, but the problem seems to be that there is no Text object somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the actual game object to your extended class?

What if you try changing

```
this.texto = new Texto({
  game: this.game,
  x: 0,
  y:0,
  text:"hola mundo"
})

this.game.add.existing(this.texto)
```